# Particle system don't stop after one shot

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a fps with a gun and when I shot the particle system continue to play . I want to do the effect of pistol shot:

I want the duration to be 0.5 sec or something

[image]

It just appears more and don't make the effect of one shot , they just fall down , what can I do? 
[image]
[image]

```css
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SpawnProjectiles : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject firePoint;
    public List<GameObject> vfx = new List<GameObject>();
    private GameObject effectToSpawn;
    public Button button;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        effectToSpawn = vfx[0];
        button.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       
        
    }
    void SpawnVFX ()
    {
        GameObject vfx;
        if(firePoint != null)
        {
            vfx = Instantiate(effectToSpawn, firePoint.transform.position, Quaternion.identity); 


        }else
        {
            Debug.Log("NoFirePoint");
        }
    }
    void TaskOnClick()
    {

        SpawnVFX();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncheck **Looping**, otherwise the Particle system will keep emitting.

Comment: I still get the problem with them fall down